# Installing UVM 1.2 in Questasim 10.2 windows

Tags: uvm, questasim

I have downloaded the UVM 1.2 from Accellera website. I am using Questasim 10.2 and my UVM version is 1.1d.

Now I copied the UVM 1.2 folder into `C:\questasim_10.2c`. Then I changed the

```
mtiUvm = $MODEL_TECH/../uvm-1.1d
```

line in `modelsim.ini` to

```
mtiUvm = $MODEL_TECH/../uvm-1.2
```

But now Questasim is showing an error that library cannot be found. How to solve this issue and install UVM 1.2 in Questasim?

Answer (score 1):

mtiUvm is a different thing. This is the Mentor Graphics version of UVM with additions to support transaction recording in Questa (and maybe some other stuff).

You don't install UVM, you compile it as any normal package:

```
vlog +incdir+<oath_to_uvm>/sv <oath_to_uvm>/sv/uvm_pkg.sv
```

This way UVM ends up in the same work library where you're compiling your other packages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 'gcc compiler' and call the uvm resource file and .dll file in run.do file.